# Convert XYZ coordinates from EPSG:2231 to EPSG:3857 (WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator)

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, ground-control

I have some ground control points (GCPs) collected using coordinate system EPSG: 2231 (Colorado North USft). I have the [data as a CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nHXXCOTMcepGSb6yfuw6nmxLhi22Uq6h/view?usp=sharing). I want to convert the X,Y,and Z coordinates to WGS84 Psuedo Mercator (EPSG: 3857), with the X and Y coordinates being in decimal degrees.

I have found the website [EPSG.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2231&t_srs=3857) which will convert the XY coordinates to Pseudo Mercator (Northing/Easting), which is a start, but how can I convert the Z coordinates?

It's my understanding there is something called a vertical reference system for coordinate systems, and that WGS84 Pseudo Mercator is specifically designated in meters. It's also my understanding that for coordinating Z coordinates between coordinate systems, I can't just do a simple feet to meters conversion. Could someone shed more light on this process/any free tools to perform this conversion?

Comment: Welcome! You first need to figure out what vertical coordinate reference system the Z values are referenced to. Are they NAVD88? Are they ellipsoidal heights based on NAD83?

Comment: You *can't* convert the 3857 coord X/Y units to degrees unless you want to visit [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island). Web Mercator's unit value is meters (though not in a way you could trust for measurement).

Comment: If you need WGS84 coordinates with decimal degrees, then you should use a geographic coordinate system (EPSG:4326) instead of a projected one like 3857.

Comment: @mkennedy I am pretty sure they are ellipsoidal based on NAD83.
Vince could you explain this further and why this conversion wouldn't work?

FSimardGIS Thanks for that advice, but due to the very specific requirements for this work project, it must be 3857, even if it isn't the best one.

Comment: The xy coordinates in Pseudo Mercator _aren't_ degrees. Converting to Pseudo Mercator will only give you values in meters, like (-11641993.70, 4941566.04) that's why you have to convert to geographic in order to get degrees. Using 4326, you can get your desired values (40.5184195, -104.5818088) (lat, lon)

Comment: Note that if you intend to use a GIS software, the final crs used for the display in your project _could_ be 3857 Pseudo Mercator, but in order to retrieve decimal degrees (latitudes and longitudes in WGS84) for your points, you still _have_ to perform a conversion from 2231 to 4326 somewhere in the process.

Comment: For your heights, you need to identify your source Vertical Datum as well as your desired output Vertical Datum, in order to perform a conversion. Examples are: NGVD29, NAVD88, NAD83 ellipsoidal, WGS84 ellipsoidal..., and you need to be really sure of your source datum, because there is a 60-foot difference between ellipsoidal and gravity-based datums in Colorado.

Comment: @FSimardGIS thank you for your clarifications, they were very helpful. Let's say my data is in 2231 and my vertical datum is NAD83 Ellipsoidal. How can I:

1. Convert those X,Y, and Z coordinates directly to 4326?
2. Convert those X,Y, and Z coordinates directly to 3857?
3. What is the most common vertical datum used in 4326?
4. What is the most common vertical datum used in 3857?

As per Q1 & 2 I've only seen tools to convert the X,Y of my 2231 data to either (lat,long) in 4326, or to (X,Y) in 3857.

Comment: Coordinates conversion can be made with several tools, like ArcGIS, Pyproj, QGIS, some websites like epsg.io, etc. Most of these tools do not perform a datum transformation between NAD83 and WGS84 by default (they consider them equal) which is okay if your desired accuracy is +- 1 m. If you require higher accuracy transformations, then you need to know the exact NAD83 version and epoch that your points are referenced to, and choose an appropriate transformation. Were these points collected with GNSS?

Comment: Also, check out [VDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/vdatumweb/vdatumweb), it has an online and desktop application that can perform conversions for vertical datums

Comment: Some common vertical datums used with WGS84 are EGM96, EGM2008, or plain ellipsoidal heights with GNSS surveys. In the Continental US, NAVD88 is very common, used with NAD83. I must warn you though about using ellipsoidal heights, they are very ill-suited for any kind of elevation-related analysis, unless you wish to see rivers flow uphill...